# Query Inner Join issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three table in a database that are joined together. The problem I am having is when I do a search for a candidate that Primary Key and Foreign Key begins with leading zeros the query will not return the data. I have confirmed that the data exist in the database. Here is an example of the query.

```
SELECT *
FROM candidate_exam
INNER JOIN candidate
    ON candidate_exam.idcandidate = candidate.idcandidate
INNER JOIN exam
    ON candidate_exam.exam_id = exam.exam_id
WHERE candidate.idcandidate = '000011111'
  AND candidate.lname = 'testlastname'
  AND candidate_exam.alpha_exam_score = 'Pass'
```

Comment: kinda weird. is the data type of `candidate.idcandidate` varchar? can you also give swample records?

Comment: Should work assuming your data types are both varchar: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63314/2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] before too long.  Please show the schema of the relevant columns of your tables; it always helps.  Showing some minimal data set and the expected and actual results also helps.